# Redirect from one url to another using 301 parmanent redirect rule in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, iis

When user hit below Url:
http://example.org/buy/parts/Vehicle/3/2012/5/76/6/1013/7/Toyota/8/Corolla
It should redirect to 
http://example.org/buy/parts/Vehicle/2012/Toyota/Corolla

Application code is in C# dotnet framework 3.5
I want to redirect Url using Redirect rule or from C# code side.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to redirect specific URL, then you could use IIS URL rewrite module redirect rule

```
  </rule>
                <rule name="redirect rule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="buy/parts/Vehicle/3/2012/5/76/6/1013/7/Toyota/8/Corolla" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="buy/parts/Vehicle/2012/Toyota/Corolla" />
                </rule>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

If you also want the URL like

BASED on year,brand. You could use this rule

```
   <rule name="redirect rule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="buy/parts/Vehicle/[^/]+/([^/]+)/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/([^/]+)/[^/]+/([^/]+)" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="buy/parts/Vehicle/{R:1}/{R:2}/{R:3}" />
                </rule>
```